# How to check circular reference for an object of container type in Python

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I want to implement a program to check if there is a circular reference in an object of container type. And luckily I found a short program in **[pymotw](https://pymotw.com/2/gc/#tracing-references)**

I pasted the source code here, however it seems to be wrong, just as the comment at the bottom of the article said.

Can I implement a correct version based on the source code?

```
import gc
import pprint
import Queue

class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.next = None
    def set_next(self, next):
        print 'Linking nodes %s.next = %s' % (self, next)
        self.next = next
    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%s)' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.name)

# Construct a graph cycle
one = Graph('one')
two = Graph('two')
three = Graph('three')
one.set_next(two)
two.set_next(three)
three.set_next(one)

print

seen = set()
to_process = Queue.Queue()

# Start with an empty object chain and Graph three.
to_process.put( ([], three) )

# Look for cycles, building the object chain for each object we find
# in the queue so we can print the full cycle when we're done.
while not to_process.empty():
    chain, next = to_process.get()
    chain = chain[:]
    chain.append(next)
    print 'Examining:', repr(next)
    seen.add(id(next))
    for r in gc.get_referents(next):
        if isinstance(r, basestring) or isinstance(r, type):
            # Ignore strings and classes
            pass
        elif id(r) in seen:
            print
            print 'Found a cycle to %s:' % r
            for i, link in enumerate(chain):
                print '  %d: ' % i,
                pprint.pprint(link)
        else:
            to_process.put( (chain, r) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the algorithm goes like:

```
   func cycleSearch(adjacentNodes, node, visited):  
       if (visited[node]):  
           if (node == start):  
               "found a path"  
           return;  
       visited[node]=YES;  
       for child in adjacentNodes[node]:  
           call cycleSearch(adjacentNodes,child,visited)
       visited[node]=NO;
```

The code you have implements Queu so you would have to modify it to fit into the Queu schema. But the algorithm stays true no matter what:

1. If I have visited the node already and it is the same as the first node, I have found a path, if it is not the same as the first node I continue (return) since I might have a cycle.
2. I set the current node to visited = YES
3. For every adjacent node to the one I am in, I recursively call this function with the childs adjacent nodes, the child node, and the start node.
4. I then set visited = NO. Because if I have reached the end the node had no adjacencies (so the end) hence it is not part of the current cycle I am looking for and i backtrack so it is as if I hadn't been there.

Comment: what is the first node in step 1? If it means the root element which we starts with scanning, the algorithm does not solve my question. What I want is to find if there is a circular reference, the root element might not in the cycle.

Comment: well the algorithm checks on the starting node but you can easily call it on all nodes of the graph if you want to check any possible cycle, something like:
visited = [NO for node in Graph]
for node in Graph:
  cycleSearch(node.adjacentElems, node, visited)

Comment: eh? I just got -2 reputation from this answer o.O
did I do something wrong?

Comment: It is because you does not provide a beautiful answer. To check circular reference on every node is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the input :D
I hate it when people just downvote and don't say why :S
I am still doing my bachelors degree so I like knowing if I'm wrong but also WHY I'm wrong ahaha

Comment: And in that case I would sugest looking into strongly connected graphs theory, we haven't yet done much so I can't really help you much there, but from what our professor told us there is an algorithm called Tarjan's (or something similar) maybe check if you find anything here on it ^^